# Type hinting for dynamic object variables

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to add variables dynamically without having to declare them beforehand (mainly so I can declare them in middle of commands), So I decided to just use an empty object and create new variables through it, but my only problem is that type hinting doesn't work when accessing the the object properties, unlike when setting values for declared var. So is there some workaround to it so I could always get accurate type hinting based on what I set inside the property in the current scope?

```js
const $: {[key: string]: any} = {}

$.some_variable = 5
```

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is not clear. `mainly so I can declare them in middle of commands` - I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: `const value = {prop_1: $.some_variable = foo()}` For stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. You can't mutate the type of a variable procedurally like this. As soon as you declare `{[key: string]: any}` then the properties of that object are unknowable to the type system.

You might think well, what if I used a function? But that would require Typescript to support [type mutating functions, and it does not](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27568), with this quote from the Typescript team:

> We think it's very valuable, but have no ideas on how to implement it without completely blowing up performance

---

If you wanted a solution that used immutable values and functions, this might work:

```
function add<
    T extends Record<string, unknown>,
    K extends string,
    V extends unknown
>(obj: T, key: K, value: V): T & { [key in K]: V } {
    return {...obj, [key]: value }
}

const a = {}
const b = add(a, 'some_variable', 5)
console.log(b.some_variable) // 5
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYBN0B5jL8gFWQFMAPGYidAZ2QCVioEAnbamZuCAcwBplIAawgIA7hAB8vXPgDSJcpRrJ2nHtPzIAagopVaQkeOASAFAgBGAKwBchfoOIBPO7P4A3VABswxO1oBKOyIAMmQAb2QAbUcnZC5kWQBdf2QAXwiZPGZiGDBmFHCAOhLLK34Y5xTkTx9idOA04GAmCHY0ZABeCKbW9osutExTVH4AcmoEAFtiAH1PTlQLL2Ix-gBWAJakSZWirwRuUwsiyZn51EXl4gDkAHo75HWgA)

But that's pretty cumbersome.

---

You can also declare a literal, and that get the type of it as an alias.

```
type TestType = typeof test

const test = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 'foo'
}
```

But you can't really build up an object key by key this way.

---

Wrapping up, you should not be afraid of the declare type, then use type pattern. It's simple, hard to screw up, and yes, also means writing code that feels like it duplicates itself. But as soon as you use that type in two places, then this investment pays off.

Comment: It's not something I want to use for the project itself. But I have a single file that serves some kind of mapping, which is a bunch of really nested class initializers with arguments and so on. So I want to use argument that were initialized in one place, in others as well. Like so;

`new foo_1(
    $.some_var = new foo_2(
        new foo_1()
    ),
    new foo_3($.some_var)
)`

And if I go and declare some of them in variables, it will break the purpose of it being a single  mapping